# UIControlState in Swift

Tags: swift, uicontrolstate

Here is my code:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16.0)
let attributes: NSDictionary? = [ NSFontAttributeName : font! ]
self.segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState:.Normal)
```

I have an error "Could not find member 'Normal' in the last line. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your `attributes` to `[NSObject : AnyObject]` and your code will be :

```
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes as [NSObject : AnyObject]?, forState: .Normal)
```

This is default syntax from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:):

```
func setTitleTextAttributes(_ attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, forState state: UIControlState)
```

Or you can cast `attributes` to `[NSObject : AnyObject]?` when you create it and code code will be:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16.0)
let attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]? = [ NSFontAttributeName : font! ]
self.segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line of your code:

```
self.segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState:.Normal)
```

to this:

```
self.segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: UIControlState.normal)
```

or you can also use the following:

```
self.segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes as? [AnyHashable : Any], forState: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's should work your code. You just restart your xcode.

Try blow Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var segment: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 26.0)
        let attributes: NSDictionary? = [ NSFontAttributeName : font! ]
       segment.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes! as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState:.Normal)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```